# How do I pass parameters to a service?

Tags: 8, symfony-services

How can parameters be passed to service? I have a class that I would like to change to a service and load other services from the container. What I don't understand is how to deal with other parameters in the constructor when calling the service.

For example, I have a `CustomService` class.

```
public function __construct(QueryFactory $query_factory, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, param1, param2) {

    $this->entity_query = $query_factory;
    $this->entity_type_manager = $entity_type_manager;

    $this->param1 = $param1;
    $this->param2 = $param2;

  }

public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
   return new static(
       $container->get('entity.query'),
       $container->get('entity_type.manager')
    );
}
```

How can I instantiate the service I would instantiate with `\Drupal::service('CustomService')`? It does not work for me; it only works when I remove the custom parameters from the constructor.

This might be a wrong approach, but I'm new to Drupal 8 and would like to use proper coding with dependency injection.