# Send email to author when content is published through scheduler

Tags: 8

I have used [Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) module with [content moderation integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler_content_moderation_integration) to publish a content automatically. It is perfectly working using the module. Now I want to add a functionality that once the content is published via cron, an email will be sent to the author of that particular content.

I have used `hook_scheduler_publish_action` to perform this action, but unfortunately I am facing some different scenario.

1. If I remove node publish code and keep only the mail sending code, the mail is fired.
2. If I remove the mail sending code and keep only node publish code, the node is published.
3. If I keep both, only mail is sent, content is not published.

**Ref**: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/scheduler/blob/8.x-1.x/scheduler.api.php

**Below code is only publishing content, not sending email.**

```
function MYMODULE_scheduler_publish_action(NodeInterface $node) {
  // node moderation state will be 'published'
  $node->set('moderation_state', 'published');
  $node->save();

  // email send to author
  $mail_params = array(
    'mail_subject' => 'run cron',
    'mail_body' => '<p>node published using scheduler</p>',
    'mail_to' => 'someone@email.com'
  );

  \Drupal::service('MYMODULE.common_service')->FunctionToSendEmail($mail_params);
}
```

**Below code is only sending email, not publishing content.**

```
function MYMODULE_scheduler_publish_action(NodeInterface $node) {  
  // email send to author
  $mail_params = array(
  'mail_subject' => 'run cron',
  'mail_body' => '<p>node published using scheduler</p>',
  'mail_to' => 'someone@email.com'
  );
  
  \Drupal::service('MYMODULE.common_service')->FunctionToSendEmail($mail_params);
  
  // node moderation state will be 'published'
  $node->set('moderation_state', 'published');
  $node->save();
}
```

That means this hook only perform the first action and ignores others.

Now my question is how will I perform multiple actions using this hook or is there any other procedure to do this?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Scheduler Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) itself do provide some events , which one of them is `PUBLISH`. So you can create an event subscriber in your module and listen to publish event like this:

```
class YourSchedulerEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
  public function publishAndSendMail(SchedulerEvent $event) {
  /** @var \Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node */
  $node = $event->getNode();
  $node->set('moderation_state', $node->publish_state->getValue());

  $event->setNode($node);

  $mail_params = array(
  'mail_subject' => 'run cron',
  'mail_body' => '<p>node published using scheduler</p>',
  'mail_to' => 'someone@email.com'
  );
  \Drupal::service('MYMODULE.common_service')->FunctionToSendEmail($mail_params); //Better to be sent as service argumnets
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    // The values in the arrays give the function names above.
    $events[SchedulerEvents::PUBLISH][] = ['publishAndSendMail'];
    return $events;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I will definitely give it a try on Monday. Can you please provide me a link or something where I can get a full list of events like `PUBLISH` provided by this Scheduler module? Thanks again.

Comment: Also, how will I send multiple parameters as array in the `\Drupal::service` method when the service parameters will be dynamic based on different node publishing scenario? The `mail_to` key will have different email ids that I need to send via the service. As per this ref, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237353/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-a-service services are not suitable in cases where I need to pass parameters from the service call.

Comment: to answer your first question you can go to scheduler module in src/SchedulerEvents.php you can find the list of events

Comment: when you want to build a service and you need more services like MYMODULE.common_service as input you can add it as argument in your services.yml file (it needs an @ to be considered as service), then if you need more parameters which are not of type services, then in a case of eventsubscriber you need to fetch them from $event, for example to get a node author you can get it from $event->node->getoWNER()

Comment: Getting the same issue with your solution. Email sent but node not published. Once I remove the mail sending code, node is published.

Comment: To answer to Souvik Das, I found this in the module:
 * The six possible Scheduler events are:
 * SchedulerEvents::PRE_PUBLISH
 * SchedulerEvents::PUBLISH
 * SchedulerEvents::PRE_UNPUBLISH
 * SchedulerEvents::UNPUBLISH
 * SchedulerEvents::PRE_PUBLISH_IMMEDIATELY
 * SchedulerEvents::PUBLISH_IMMEDIATELY.